# How to move files which are named as a variable in a for loop in bash?

Tags: bash

I am trying to make a bash script that would ask me the number of files I want to move in a certain target directory and then it would ask me one by one the directory's of the files I want to move.
Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "how many files do you want to move? "

#asking user the number of files they want to move and putting that number in a variable called FILENUM which would later be used in the for statement 
 
read FILENUM

echo "what is the target directory? "

#asking user the directory in which he want the files to be moved to... and putting it in a variable called TARDIR and the making a dir using the variable TARDIR

read -e TARDIR

mkdir "$TARDIR"

#making a for loop that will stop when a is equal to variable FILENUM
for a in $( seq 1 $FILENUM )  
do
    echo "what is the directory of file.$a : "

    read -e FILEDIR$a            #asking user the directory of the file he want to move.This process will make a unique variable (for every iteration in the for loop) in which the directory is stored
    
    mv "$FILEDIR$a" "$TARDIR"   #this is where the code breaks. 
done

read
```

Comment: Use `bash -x yourScript.sh` to debug what goes wrong : it will print the commands as they are run with the variables expanded into their values

Comment: `this is where the code breaks.` What do you mean by "breaks"? Could you describe what exactly happens? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it? What happens, specifically?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because you have $a appended after $FILEDIR which is changing the name of the file you want to move. If you remove the $a after $FILEDIR everything will work just fine. You may also want to add a test for if the TARDIR exists like this.

```
if [[ ! -d $TARDIR ]]; then 
 mkdir $TARDIR
fi
```

So revised your script would probably look something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "how many files do you want to move? "

#asking user the number of files they want to move and putting that number in a variable called FILENUM which would late
r be used in the for statement

read FILENUM

echo "what is the target directory? "

#asking user the directory in which he want the files to be moved to... and putting it in a variable called TARDIR and t
he making a dir using the variable TARDIR

read -e TARDIR

if [[ ! -d $TARDIR ]]; then
  mkdir "$TARDIR"
fi

#making a for loop that will stop when a is equal to variable FILENUM
for a in $( seq 1 $FILENUM )
do
    echo "what is the directory of file $a: "

    read -e FILEDIR         #asking user the directory of the file he want to move.This process will make a unique varia
ble (for every iteration in the for loop) in which the directory is stored

    mv "$FILEDIR" "$TARDIR"   #this is where the code breaks.
done

read
```

Comment: Thnx greatly appreciate it.